# Confused about this while statement

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, user-input

I wrote this program for class and I can't seem to get the while loop to work.. I don't know where I am wrong, it's probably a small error which I know I make tons of... Thanks! PS I'm new to this stuff so be easy on me if it is something small :P

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 10
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define MAXNUM 5

/***************
prototypes
***************/
void make_empty(int *top);
int is_full(int *top);
int push(int content[], int maxnum, int newnum, int *top);
int pop(int contents[], int maxmun, int *top);
void printStack(int contents[], int maxnum, int *top);
int is_empty(int *top);
int search(const int content[], int maxnum, int num);

// main function
int main(void)
{
    int popNum = 0;
    int foundIndex = -1;
    int i;
    int contents[STACK_SIZE] = { 0 };
    int top = 0;
    int input = 0;


    while (! == 0)
    {
        printf("/n/nPick a number from 1 to 5, type the number then press enter: ");
        switch (input)
        {
        case 1:
            push(contents, MAXNUM, popNum, &top);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (pop(contents, MAXNUM, &top) <= 0)
                printf("Error popping stack \n");
            break;
        case 3:
            make_empty(&top);
            break;
        case 4:
            printStack(contents, MAXNUM, &top);
        }//End Loop Switch

    }

} // end main()

/******************************************
**
** make_empty function **
**
******************************************/

void make_empty(int *top)
{
    *top = 0;
}

/******************************************
**
** is_empty function **
**
******************************************/

int is_empty(int *top)
{
    if (*top == 0)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

/******************************************
**
** is_full function **
**
******************************************/

int is_full(int *top)
{
    static int nCalls = 0; // static variable

    nCalls++;
    if (*top == STACK_SIZE)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

/******************************************
**
** push function **
**
******************************************/

int push(int content[], int maxnum, int newnum, int *top)
{
    int nCalls = 0;
    nCalls++;
    if (is_full(top))
        return FALSE;
    else
        content[(*top)++] = newnum;
}

/******************************************
**
** pop function **
**
******************************************/

int pop(int contents[], int maxmun, int *top)
{
    if (is_empty(top))
        return FALSE;
    else
        return contents[--(*top)];
}

/*******************************
**
** printStack fuction **
**
******************************/
void printStack(int contents[], int maxnum, int *top)
{
    int i;
    if (!is_empty(top))
    {
        for (i = 0; i < *top; i++)
            printf("Number %d = %d\n", i, contents[i]);
    }
    else
        printf("Stack is empty");
}

/*******************************
**
** search function **
**
******************************/
int search(const int content[], int maxnum, int num)
{

    int fIndex = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxnum; i++)
    {
        if (content[i] == num)
        {
            fIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return (fIndex);

}

/*




*/
```

Comment: First off, most people on SO don't like to give homework help. You should ask your TA/Instructors. That said, your question isn't very clear; what exactly about your while loop isn't working. Are you getting an exception? Is it running infinitely? Is your code not compiling?

Comment: `while (! == 0)` invalid.

Comment: The way to write code is to start with something small and simple that works, then add complexity a little at a time, test at every step and develop new functionality in isolation. You ought to have tried a simple `while` loop without user I/O or functions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in every textbook on the subject and takes mere seconds to find with a search engine. It is unlikely to be of use to future readers.

Comment: I was asking a simple question, yes it does build properly but the loop is broken. I am not sure how to fix it though.. This isn't a homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1**  >> `while (! == 0)`

If you want to loop unconditionally, use `while (1)`, and inside `switch` case, add a default (or numbered) case to hold a `break` statement to come of the loop.

**Issue 2**  >> `switch (input)`

You *seem to* plan for asking for user input, but you did not code for that. before *switching* based on input value, you need to get the value from the user and store into `input` variable. Make use of `scanf()` function. Read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) for details.

Answer (score 0):

This while loop is all wrong ... You are using switch case for input... And ***input***=0 always... You are not doing scanf to get the input value... How will other functions get invoked if ***input*** doesnot change?....